# How to call static methods on a protocol if they are defined in a protocol extension?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift2, protocol-extension

```
protocol Car {
    static func foo() 
}

struct Truck : Car {

}

extension Car {
    static func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}

Car.foo() // Does not work  
// Error: Car does not have a member named foo

Truck.foo() // Works
```

Xcode autocompletes the `Car.foo()` correctly, so what i'm asking is if its a bug that it doesn't compile (says it does not have a member named foo()). Could you call static methods directly on the protocol if they are defined in a protocol extension?

Comment: Car is not an object so you can't send it any messages.

Comment: This feels like a bug to me. Since the default implementation binds actual functionality directly to the protocol, it should be callable on the protocol itself.

Comment: @hennes "the default implementation binds actual functionality directly to the protocol" is not a true statement. The default implementation binds functionality to class and structs which conform to the protocol. There are [reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_inheritance#The_diamond_problem) protocols don't have implementations.

Comment: What seems like a bug is that Xcode actually suggest the autocomplete, if its not possible it should not do that

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apple [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID275)

> Protocols do not actually implement any functionality themselves.
> Nonetheless, any protocol you create will become a fully-fledged type
> for use in your code.

Therefore, you cannot call static methods directly of protocol.

Comment: They can do it with a simple hack. Here is my related answer. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59275651/1163992

Answer (score 1):

No, the error message isn't good, but it's telling you the correct thing.

Think of it this way, you can't have

```
protocol Car {
    static func foo() {
        print("bar")
    }
}
```

This compiles with the error "Protocol methods may not have bodies".

Protocol extensions don't add abilities to protocols which don't exist.

Comment: In Swift 2 protocol extensions can actually add default implementations.

Comment: @hennes Yes, they add default implementations to classes and structs… not protocols. A protocol has no implementation.

Comment: [This](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521) says otherwise, or am I mistaken?

Comment: @hennes [Protocols can be extended to provide method and property implementations to **conforming types**](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Protocols.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH25-ID521). The new protocol extension adds to a **class** or **struct** conforming to the protocol, but the protocol is still just a protocol. *Protocols don't have an implementation.*

Comment: So the point is that the default implementation is added to each conforming class/struct instead of the protocol. I see your point. Still, this feels a bit weird to me.