# How can I call a static function on a protocol in a generic way?

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

Is there a point to declaring a static function on a protocol? The client using the protocol has to call the function on a type conforming to the protocol anyway right? That breaks the idea of not having to know the type conforming to the protocol IMO. Is there a way to call the static function on the protocol in a way where I don't have to know the actual type conforming to my protocol?

Comment: Highly recommend you to see this [question and its accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53746921/swift-cant-infer-generic-type-when-generic-type-is-being-passed-through-a-param)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Nice question. Here is my humble point of view:

### Is there a point to declaring a static function on a protocol?

Pretty much the same as having instance methods declared in a protocol.

### The client using the protocol has to call the function on a type conforming to the protocol anyway right?

Yes, exactly like instance functions.

### That breaks the idea of not having to know the type conforming to the protocol IMO.

Nope. Look at the following code:

```
protocol Feline {
    var name: String { get }
    static func createRandomFeline() -> Feline
    init()
}

extension Feline {
    static func createRandomFeline() -> Feline {
        return arc4random_uniform(2) > 0 ? Tiger() : Leopard()
    }
}

class Tiger: Feline {
    let name = "Tiger"
    required init() {}
}

class Leopard: Feline {
    let name = "Leopard"
    required init() {}
}

let feline: Feline = arc4random_uniform(2) > 0 ? Tiger() : Leopard()
let anotherFeline = feline.dynamicType.createRandomFeline()
```

I don't know the real type inside the variable `feline`. I just know that it does conform to `Feline`. However I am invoking a static protocol method.

### Is there a better way to do this?

I see, you would like to call a static method/function declared in a protocol without creating a value that conforms to the protocol.

Something like this:

```
Feline.createRandomFeline() // DANGER: compiler is not happy now
```

Honestly I don't know the reason why this is not possible.

Comment: Yes, I understood what you mean after having posted my answer. I updated my last answer but unfortunately I cannot provide a reason behind this design decision.

Comment: Maybe if I can store a reference to `ProtocolName`'s type I can call the static function on that type?? I'll mess with it real quick.

Comment: Wooooooooow, that works. I'll update my question with some code.

Comment: The reason why I don't really like the last two lines starting with `let feline: Feline ...` is that I really don't want or need to have an instance of `Feline` in order to call the static function. The only reason that has to be done is to find out the underlying type conforming to that protocol.

Comment: Declare `static func createRandomFeline() -> Feline` as `static func createRandomFeline() -> Self`. Now, do you see the reason? :) A protocol has no `self`, therefore you cannot call methods on it.

Answer (score 17):

yes this is possible:

**Swift 3**

```
protocol Thing {
  static func genericFunction()
}

//... in another file

var things:[Thing] = []

for thing in things {
  type(of: thing).genericFunction()
}
```

Comment: this is not a generic function.

Comment: You're calling it on instances. I think the idea is to have a static method that creates the instances.

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer

Answer (score 8):

Thank you @appzYourLife for the help! Your answer inspired my answer.

@appzYourLife answered my question. I had an underlying issue I was trying to resolve and the following code resolves my issue, so I'll post this here, maybe it helps someone with my same underlying question:

```
 protocol MyProtocol {
     static func aStaticFunc()
 }

 class SomeClassThatUsesMyProtocolButDoesntConformToIt {

     var myProtocolType: MyProtocol.Type
     init(protocolType: MyProtocol.Type) {
         myProtocolType = protocolType
     }

     func aFunction() {
         myProtocolType.aStaticFunc()
     }
 }
```

Comment: How do you create an instance of SomeClassThatUsesMyProtocolButDoesntConformToIt?

Comment: @KoCMoHaBTa Assuming you have (eg.) `struct S: MyProtocol {…}`, you simply call `SomeClassThatUsesMyProtocolButDoesntConformToIt(protocolType: S.self)`

Answer (score 5):

I created another solution for this case. IMHO this is quite clean and simple.

First, create a protocol for accessing instance type.

```swift
protocol TypeAccessible {
    func type() -> Self.Type
}

extension TypeAccessible {
    func type() -> Self.Type {
        return Swift.type(of: self)
    }
}
```

then create your concrete class as here. The point is your protocol should conform to `TypeAccessible` protocol.

```swift
protocol FooProtocol: TypeAccessible {
    static func bar()
}

class Foo: FooProtocol {
    static func bar() { }
}
```

On call site use it as

```swift
let instance: FooProtocol = Foo()
instance.type().bar()
```

For further use cases, just make sure your protocols conform to `TypeAccessible` and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party on this one.

Here's my solution for "adding" static properties/functions/types to a protocol using `typealias`.

For example:

```
enum PropertyScope {
    case all
    case none
}

struct PropertyNotifications {

    static var propertyDidChange = 
                         Notification.Name("propertyDidChangeNotification")

}

protocol Property {

    typealias Scope = PropertyScope

    typealias Notifications = PropertyNotifications

    var scope: Scope { get set }

}
```

Then you can do this anywhere in your code:

```
func postNotification() {
    let scope: Property.Scope = .all

    NotificationCenter.post(name: Property.Notifications.propertyDidChange,
                            object: scope)

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using protocols like Java interfaces is rarely a good idea. They are meta types, meant for defining contracts, which is an entirely different kind of thing.

That being said, just for the point of understanding, I find the most simple and effective way for creating the equivalent of a static factory method of a protocol to write a free function.

It should contain the protocol's name, hoping that that will prevent name clashes, and improve discoverability.

In other languages, createP would be a static member of P, named create and be called as P.create(...), which would drastically improve discoverability and guarantee to prevent name clashes.

In swift, though, this is not an option for protocols, so if protocols are for some reason really actually used as a replacement for interfaces, at least including the protocol's name in the function's name is an ugly workaround that's still slightly better than nothing.

P.S. in case the goal is actually to achieve something like an inheritance hierarchy with structs, union style enums are the tool that's meant to serve that purpose :)

```
protocol P
{
    var x: Int { get }
}

func createP() -> P
{
    if (todayIsMonday())
    {
        return A()
    }
    else
    {
        return B()
    }
}

class A: P
{
    var x = 5
}

class B: P
{
    var x = 7
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an answer so much as it is an extension to the question.  Say I have:

```
@objc public protocol InteractivelyNameable: Nameable {

    static func alertViewForNaming(completion:@escaping((_ success: Bool, _ didCancel: Bool, _ error: Error?) -> Void)) -> UIAlertController?
}
```

And I have a generic view controller that manages various types (generic type is .fetchableObjectType... basically NSFetchResult).  I need to check if a specific object type conforms to the protocol, and if so, invoke it.

something like:

```
    // valid swift code
    if self.dataSource.fetchableObjectType is InteractivelyNameable {

        // not valid swift code
        if let alert = (self.dataSource.fetchableObjectType as InteractivelyNameable).alertViewForNaming(....)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a situation where I need to create same `DomainModel` object from `2` different response. so this (`static` method in `protocol` helped me) approach helped me.

```
protocol BaseResponseKeyList: CodingKey {
   static func getNameKey()->Self
}

enum FirstResponseKeyList: String, BaseResponseKeyList {
    case name

    func getNameKey()->FirstResponseKeyList {
       return .name
    }
}

enum SecondResponseKeyList: String, BaseResponseKeyList {
    case userName

    func getNameKey()->SecondResponseKeyList {
       return .userName
    }
}

struct MyDomainModel<T:BaseResponseKeyList> : Decodable {
    var name:String?

    required init(from d:Decoder) {
       do {
            let container = try d.container(keyedBy:T.self)
            name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey:T.getNameKey())
        }catch(_) {
            print("error")
        }
    }
}

let myDomainModel = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyDomainModel <FirstResponseKeyList>.self, from: data)
let myDomainModel2 = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyDomainModel <SecondResponseKeyList>.self, from: data2)
```